# How to tell what cause a heat - CPU, thermal paste or water cooler?

Tags: cpu, cooling

I have PC for 6 years, half of year ago I bought new CPU, it wasn't working properly so I returned, and put my old CPU, but since than I have an issue - sometimes my CPU heats with no reason.
Usually when I start my PC temperature of CPU cores is about 40 degrees, but sometimes, like once per 2 weeks it's 100 degrees.
When it's hot I just take off water cooler, fix thermal paste(smudge with finger or put new paste) and put cooler back, and it works fine for couple weeks.
I thinks there might be 3 reasons:

1. CPU was broken when I changed it
2. New thermal paste is bad, I use ARCTIC MX-4, it's number one selling paste on Amazon
3. Water cooler! Looks like it works, I see 2000 RPM when CPU is hot, and I see it works, the fan is spinning, also I see two water tubes, one of them is hot and other is not, so looks like it works, is it possible that it needs to change water or do some maintenance?

It can't be viruses, because CPU loaded on 2%, and heated to 100 degrees.

The CPU:
[image: CPU image]

The cooler:
[image: Cooler image]

How to figure out what is wrong? How do you test such situation?

Comment: So basically you’re saying you removed and put back the heat sink a lot, right? Are you absolutely sure it’s still seated properly? Also, that’s a lot of thermal paste. Probably too much.

Comment: Daniel B, there is 4 points above cooler, and this points using to push coller to cpu, so it should be seated properly, but I'm not 100% sure. Also next time I'll try to use less paste

Comment: Water pumps don’t work forever.  This an AIO or a custom loop?

Comment: Ramhound, it's AIO

Answer (score 0):

> How to tell what cause a heat - CPU, thermal paste or water cooler?

Water cools and does not heat. It can get hot but it is a cooling agent.

Thermal paste is a heat conductor, not a heat generator.

CPU generates heat in operation.

So carefully check your CPU and that it is properly seated with the proper (thin layer) amount of thermal compound as the CPU is the very most likely candidate causing heat generation.